# One doctrine2 entity for many localized tables

Tags: doctrine-orm, entity

I'm building application where I need to sort many data by countries. And I decided to use separate tables for it.

For example I need to implement shop table with fields like

1. id
2. title
3. location
4. etc..

And I need separate data to localized tables like:

1. shops_uk
2. shops_us
3. shops_cz
4. etc.

But if I work as usually I need to create many entities for it like: ShopUK, ShopUS...

**Question**: How can I organise it with doctrine2. How to get data from localized table using 1 entity?